# How to create possible image urls and check if they exist with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I am working on a website that uses its own language, similar to Smarty. It has a very rough set of functions built into a template "created" for me. This template does not offer a function to display images of cart items. So, I have to "guess" what the images' URLs are.

Since I cannot create any PHP-like functions in the template, I have to use JavaScript/jQuery.

**What I need to do:**
Create a few possible URLs, check to see if I guessed the URL correctly. If so, then I need to replace a `<div>`'s background image with the valid image URL.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="session-menu">
    
    <li class="drop-down cart">
        
        <a href="/store/go/basket/" class="icon-cart">
            Shopping Cart
        </a>
        
        <div class="drop drop-right">
            <ul>
                <li data-name="Intel i7 4770K" data-code="intel-4770k" data-qty="1">
                    <div class="image">
                        <a href="/Intel-i7-4770K/"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="/Intel-i7-4770K/">Intel 4770K</a>
                        <span class="qty">Quantity: 1</span>
                        <span class="price">Price: $275</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </li>

</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var dirs = '/product_images/18/4301/';
var ext = '.jpg';
var element = $('#session-menu .cart li');

$('#session-menu .cart li').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    for (var i in data){
        console.log(data[i]);
        checkUrl(createUrl(data[i]));
    }
});

function createUrl(val) {
    var imgStr = dirs + val.replace(/ |\.|\//g, '-').replace(/"|'/g, '').toLowerCase().toString() + ext;
    
    console.log(imgStr + ' has been made');
    
    return imgStr;
}

function checkUrl(img) {
    $.ajax({
        url: img,
        type: "HEAD",
        success: function() { console.log(img + ' exists'); changeBgImg(img); },
        error: function () { console.log(img + ' does not exist'); }
    });
}

function changeBgImg(img) {
    $('#session-menu .cart li .image').children('a').css('background-image', img);
}
```

The images (if they exist) are in the form of '/product_images/18/4301/intel-i7-4770k', '/product_images/18/4301/intel-4770k', or '/product_images/18/4301/large-intel-4770k'.

I really would prefer to do this in a jQuery plugin, if possible.

I had a different script doing essentially the same thing earlier, but all of the $.ajax checks came back successful? Even though the image did not exist. Even with variations of the above, the checks always came back successful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a get request?

```
function checkUrl(img) {
    $.ajax({
        url: img,
        type: "GET",
        success: function() { console.log(img + ' exists'); changeBgImg(img); },
        error: function () { console.log(img + ' does not exist'); }
    });
}
```

I just tested it on my own site. When linking to an existing image, it came back successful. When linking to a non-existing image, it came back with an error.

Comment: For sure, you are right, that does work too. I just figured this out actually... I DID NOT figure out why I was not getting any errors on the ones that do not exist. Maybe the images are dynamically created, thus causing some issue. I'm updating my answer now :)

Comment: I am now getting ajax error responses on the invalid URLs. I must have just had some bad script before... Idk

Answer (score 0):

So I had to remove the `data-qty` attribute because the script through an error with it in there... I also had to pass the element's "$(this)" through the functions so I could eventually change the BG on that specific element when I found a valid image... It seems like I could structure this script differently to avoid having to pass that through multiple functions... Maybe just set a variable outside of the functions... Yeah :)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="session-menu">

    <li class="drop-down cart">

        <a href="/store/go/basket/" class="icon-cart">
            Shopping Cart
        </a>

        <div class="drop drop-right">
            <ul>
                <li data-name="Intel i7 4770K" data-code="intel-4770k">
                    <div class="image">
                        <a href="/Intel-i7-4770K/"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="/Intel-i7-4770K/">Intel 4770K</a>
                        <span class="qty">Quantity: 1</span>
                        <span class="price">Price: $275</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </li>

</ul>
```

The JS is still very unpleasant to me. Seems like it could be composed much better. Like I said, I will need to do this set of functions on some other things around our site. Would be nice to have as a plugin, but tidier...

ALSO, It seems like I am guessing multiple valid URLs (I checked- and it is finding multiple images for each item). So how can I adjust the below to quit guessing URLs when it finds a valid one. And should there be some kind of priority system in place? Like "IF data-name URL AND data-code is valid THEN use data-name URL"?

**JS**

```
var dirs = '/product_images/18/4301/';
var ext = '.jpg';
var element = $('#session-menu .cart li');

element.each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    for (var i in data){
        checkUrl(createUrl(data[i]), $(this));
    }
});

function createUrl(val) {
    var imgStr = dirs + val.replace(/ |\.|\//g, '-').replace(/"|'/g, '').toLowerCase().toString() + ext;

    return imgStr;
}

function checkUrl(img, el) {
    $.ajax({
        url: img,
        type: "HEAD",
        success: function() { console.log(img + ' exists, changing background image...'); changeBgImg(img, el); },
        error: function () { console.log(img + ' does not exist'); }
    });
}

function changeBgImg(img, el) {
    el.find('.image a').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
}
```